# Why are some SMD components cylindrical?

Tags: components, packages

Outside of fuses or similar socketed parts, why are there cylindrical SMD components - such as this Zener (package DO-213AA):

[image: cylindrical Zener diode]

I feel like this would be a pain in assembly in general, and a nightmare if hand-soldering becomes necessary.

Comment: Answered by wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_electrode_leadless_face

Comment: You can get tweezers shaped to hold them, e.g. [these ones by Wiha](https://www.wiha.com/gb/en/tools/tweezers/professional-esd-smd-tweezers/1078/smd-tweezers-professional-esd) or [these by Ideal-Tek](https://www.ideal-tek.com/scheda.php?m=search&f=8&c=esd%20epoxy%20coated%20tweezers&l=3&idp=868).

Comment: Hand-soldering these isn't really any more difficult than soldering other SMD components of similar size. (Yes, tweezers are almost a must-have, but this is also true for 0805's, 0603's etc. Just loosen your grip a bit, don't squeeze hard enough to tiddleywink the part across the room.)

Comment: I like to solder these MELF diodes, because they are huge, easy to hold by tweezers, easy to solder. Why do you think they are difficult to solder?

Comment: There's an old EE joke that MELF stands for Most End up Lying on the Floor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a MELF (metal electrode leadless face), which is a relatively less common type of SMD component.  Typically they're either resistors or diodes, and they're used in situations where high reliability and high temperature operation is required.

Compared to a normal 0805 or similar rectangular resistor, the conductive area can be cylindrical around the output, giving more area per package size which is helpful for dissipation and stability.

Compared to a normal chip diode, the diode junction can be sealed into the tube and then bonded to the end caps with high conductivity material, giving good thermal performance and high reliability.